# Does Postman's Chrome Interceptor still work with the standalone version of Postman?

Tags: postman, postman-native-app

I've previously used the Postman Chrome's Extension along with the [Postman Interceptor Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo/related?hl=en) to capture HTTP requests made from Chrome in Postman.

However, now that Postman has migrated from a Chrome extension to a stand-alone application, I'm having trouble reproducing this functionality in the stand-alone version of Postman (v5.5.0).

Postman's documentation suggests that it is still possible [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/interceptor_extension) however the screenshots don't match the latest version of the app.

For instance, in Postman instead of seeing an icon which looks like a satellite, I see an icon which looks like a satellite dish:

[image]

Clicking this image results in a `PROXY SETTINGS` dialog where I am asked to select a Port.

When I choose the default of `5555`, turn on the interceptor extension in Chrome and make requests from Chrome, I don't see the requests appearing in Postman.

Comment: Not a solution for the stand-alone app, but as a workaround, I reverted back to the (deprecated) [Postman Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop), and it seems to be working fine (for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It would seem as though Postman has now re-added this functionality to the native app](https://blog.getpostman.com/2019/06/24/introducing-interceptor-integration-for-native-postman-apps):

> With the release of Postman v7.2, Interceptor is back. However, its functionality has changed a bit – the Interceptor Integration only syncs cookies. Now you can specify browser domains in Postman and Interceptor will capture cookies for those sites and sync them to your instance of Postman. You cannot currently capture requests using Interceptor since Postman’s built-in proxy already enables this.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to get requests from browser, like if you used to use in postman chrome app. It's very easy to do it.

Expected:

- Firefox browser
- Foxy proxy addon (to FF)
- postman standalone

Now, steps:

1. On windows CMD -> 'ipconfig', and copy your IP addres
2. Run FF and click on Foxy Proxy extension
3. Set title, in "IP addres" paste your ip addres (step 1), set port 5555 and save.
4. In FF on toolbar select your created proxy
5. Open postman
6. Click 'satelite' - capture Api req...
7. set port 5555
8. Target eg. history

Now requests from FF should be displayed in History

Comment: I can reproduce these steps to get this to work.  Is there a similar extension so that this can be done in Google Chrome instead of Firefox?

Comment: Did you try eg. FoxyProxy Standard for chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install Interceptor Bridge for native apps https://community.getpostman.com/t/interceptor-integration-for-postman-native-apps/5290

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem, Jacob.
I need the Interceptor to capture the XDEBUG_SESSION cookie and get my debug working.

Here is my solution:
In Postman on the right hand side you can add Cookies.
I added my XDEBUG_SESSION cookie there and voila, xdebug is working again.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand this response.  Where is this XDEBUG_SESSION cookie coming from?