# Capture HTTP request using Postman native app

Tags: api, request, native, postman, google-chrome-app

I have been using the **Postman Chrome** app for my API developments.

I can simply turn on the request capture from chrome and the interceptor from the **Postman Chrome** app, and like magic, all the requests *(headers, body, ..)* would be captured by the app.

Off late I have been getting a notification that the **Postman native** app is available and the support for the Chrome app would be soon stopped.

I downloaded the native app and it looks great but couldn't figure a way to capture requests with it. I googled a lot but couldn't find a solution.

I read [this](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests) from the Postman documentation and found it quite confusing and I don't think that's not what I want.

I would really appreciate a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The same interceptor functionality isn’t available in the native app yet, looks like it’s still on the Postman roadmap but no time scale for when this will be completed yet. Some discussion were captured in this Github issue:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-chrome-interceptor/issues/56

There is a workaround provided here but again, that’s probably not what you want. [Does Postman's Chrome Interceptor still work with the standalone version of postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47768912/6028443)

Alternatively, you could use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) as a web proxy to capture the traffic, this would provide you with all the details for  any of your requests. Worth checking out.

Comment: Thank you @Danny. Found on [postman blog](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/03/14/going-native/#comment-3627903653) that  a interceptor like feature is in work. Will try fiddler once.

Comment: Cool, Fiddler might not solve the problem in your context, there was obviously a reason why you were using the interceptor but it’ll give you all the info you need about the request and a bunch of useful functionality on top.